# Fetching initial loading data in React server side rendering

Tags: reactjs

What is the best practice to fetch initial loading data from a API in React server side rendering?
I had tried loading the initial data in the constructor method. But it's not working.

Comment: Would be great if you add some additional information to your question. Code? Problem? Attempts? Questions without these are usually closed as too broad or simply don't receive any answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategies for server-side rendering of asynchronously initialized React.js components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983001/strategies-for-server-side-rendering-of-asynchronously-initialized-react-js-comp)

Comment: I need to fetch the data from an external API and use that data to render the component. How should i go about it. Should i hit the external api in the constructor method for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using redux-saga to help you fetch the initial data on server side.

Below is a snippet from my [React example that uses Redux Saga and Hapi for Server-side Rendering](https://github.com/codeBelt/hapi-react-hot-loader-example)

```
class ReactController {

    _html = null;

    mapRoutes(server) {
        server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/{route*}',
            handler: async (request, reply) => {
                const store = ProviderService.createProviderStore({}, true);
                const context = {};
                const app = (
                    <RouterWrapper
                        store={store}
                        location={request.path}
                        context={context}
                        isServerSide={true}
                    />
                );

                this._html = (this._html === null) ? await this._loadHtmlFile() : this._html;

                store.runSaga(rootSaga).done.then(async () => {
                    const renderedHtml = renderToString(app);
                    const state = store.getState();
                    const initialState = {
                        ...state,
                        renderReducer: {
                            isServerSide: true,
                        },
                    };

                    const html = this._html
                        .slice(0)
                        .replace('{title}', state.metaReducer.title)
                        .replace('{description}', state.metaReducer.description)
                        .replace('{content}', renderedHtml)
                        .replace('{state}', JSON.stringify(initialState));

                    if (context.url) {
                        console.info('context', context);
                    }

                    reply(html);
                });

                renderToString(app);

                store.endSaga();
            },
        });
    }

    async _loadHtmlFile() {
        const htmlPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/index.html');

        return fse.readFile(htmlPath, 'utf8');
    }

}
```